# Xceed DateTimePicker from 0:00 to 24:00

Tags: c#, wpf, datetimepicker, xceed

I am using the TimePicker from exceed and I want the user to input hours.

I am facing the problem that I cannot allow the user to pick 24:00, because that would be 00:00 of the next day...

This is my current XAML, it allows the user only to enter a value up to 23:45

```
<xceedWpfToolkit:TimePicker     AllowSpin="True"
                                Format="Custom"
                                FormatString="HH:mm"
                                Maximum="01.01.0001 23:45:00"
                                Minimum="01.01.0001 00:00:00"
                                StartTime="0"
                                TimeInterval=15
                                Value="{Binding Path=Duration,
                                                ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                                                NotifyOnValidationError=True,
                                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

How can I configure the TimePicker to support 0:00 to 24:00?

Comment: To clarify: did you mean "support 0:00 to 23:59"? Suggestion: use a converter which changes an input of 24:00 to 0:00 next day.

Comment: Support from 0:00 to 23:59.999 but displayed as 24:00. According to wikipedia 24:00 exists: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock. My users sometime have to input 24h, for example when they worked from 16:00 to 24:00.

Comment: Then I suppose, that you can't acchieve that, as `Minimum` and `Maximum` are of type DateTime, which doesn't support hour values beyond 23 (throws an  `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`). So if a converter doesn't work for you (or with XCeed) I don't see a solution.